# If $F(x + iy) = \frac{Q}{2\pi}\ln (x + iy)$, how to prove that $\phi(x,y) = \frac{Q}{2\pi}\ln (\sqrt{x^2 + y^2})$?

Tags: complex-analysis, fluid-dynamics, potential-theory

The potential flow theory states that
$$
F(z) = \phi + i\psi
$$
where $z = x + iy$
In case of a source/sink, we have 
$$
F(z) = \frac{Q}{2\pi}\ln z\tag{1}
$$
$$
\phi(x,y) = \frac{Q}{2\pi}\ln (\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}) \quad \text{or}\quad \phi(r,\theta) = \frac{Q}{2\pi}\ln(r)\tag{2}
$$
$$
\psi(x,y) = \frac{Q}{2\pi}\arctan{\frac{y}{x}} \quad \text{or}\quad \phi(r,\theta) = \frac{Q}{2\pi}\theta\tag{3}
$$
how do we go from (1) to (2) and from (1) to (3)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a matter of the definition of the complex logarithm. If $z = r e^{i \theta}$ for $\theta \in (-\pi, \pi],$ the principal value of the complex logarithm of $z$ is defined as
\begin{equation*}
\mathrm{Log}(z)= \mathrm{ln}(r) + i\theta.
\end{equation*}
So given $z = x + iy,$
\begin{equation}
F(z) = \frac{Q}{2\pi}(\mathrm{ln}(r) + i \theta),
\end{equation}
where $r = |z| = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$ and $\theta = \mathrm{Arg}(z)$. Comparing to
\begin{equation}
F(z) = \phi + i \psi
\end{equation}
and equating the real and imaginary parts gives $(2)$ and $(3)$.

Note also that the formula $\mathrm{Arg}{(x + iy)} = \mathrm{arctan}{\frac{y}{x}}$ is only valid for $x > 0$. A more general formula makes use of the $\mathrm{atan2}$ function.

Comment: many thanks @Zac. For the sake of interest, what is the atan2 function. Could you provide a insighful link?

Comment: The Wikipedia page [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2) on the $\mathrm{atan2}$ function gives a reasonable explanation. A problem with using the $\mathrm{arctan}$ formula is that the range of $\mathrm{arctan}$ is $(- \pi/2, \pi/2)$, so it will never give a correct argument for a complex number whose real component is less than zero (for example $-1 + i$.) The $\mathrm{atan2}$ function fixes this by adding or subtracting $\pi$ as appropriate. Often things will still work out if we stick with the $\mathrm{arctan}$ formula, but it can be good to know about its shortcomings!